# How do I add to a spatial index in OrientDB?

Tags: lucene, orientdb

I'm using OrientDB 2.0 from the studio. I created a Lucene spatial index successfully, using the code from the documentation:

`CREATE class Place extends V`

`CREATE property Place.name string`

`CREATE property Place.latitude double`

`CREATE property Place.longitude double`

`CREATE INDEX Place.l_lon ON Place(latitude,longitude) SPATIAL ENGINE LUCENE`

I then created some `Place` objects with `latitude` and `longitude`.

When I attempt to do a spatial search using the documented format

`select from Class where [<lat-field>,<long-field>] NEAR [<x>,<y>]`

the search completes without error but returns no results, even when I pass in the exact coordinates of one of the `Place` objects.

I also tried querying the index directly using

`select from index:Place.l_lon`

which also succeeded without error but returned no results. I'm thinking that my index may be empty. I tried rebuilding it from the schema editor but still no result. Also, as far as I can tell, there's no way to manually add composite entries like location coordinates to an index. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify max distance with syntax

```
select  from Class where [<lat-field>,<long-field>,$spatial] NEAR [<x>,<y>,{"maxDistance": distance}]
```

Comment: That worked. I wonder if there are any performance implications from the different approach.